# How to actually write a newline to a string

Tags: ruby, string-substitution

How can I make this

```
content[i].gsub("\n", "\\n")
```

write (something like) this to a file

```
str = "some text\n"
```

I'm writing a piece of code to take a file and build a single string out of it that can be inserted back into the source code your working with, if that helps at all

If I'm mistaken and my error is actually somewhere else in the code, here is:

```
#!/bin/usr/ruby
#reads a file and parses into a single string declaration in language of choice
#another little snippet to make my job easier when writing lots of code
#programmed by michael ward
# h3xc0ntr0l@gmail.com | gists.github.com/michaelfward


# ***************************************
#              example scrips
#  with writefiles 
#   | writefiles [file with paths] [file to write*]
#   | makestring [file to write* (actually is read, but same as above)] [lang] 
#****************************************


def readFile(path)
  fd = File.open(path, "r")
  content = []
  fd.each_line {|x| content.push(x)}
  content = fixnewlines(content)
  str = content.join()
  str
end

def fixnewlines(content)
  content.each_index do |i|
    content[i].gsub("\n", "\\n")
  end
end

def usage
  puts "makestring [file to read] [language output]"
  exit
end

langs = {"rb"=>"str =", "js" => "var str =", "c"=> "char str[] ="}

usage unless ARGV.length == 2
lang = ARGV[1]
path = ARGV[0]
str = readFile(path)
if langs[lang] == nil
  if lang == "c++" || lang == "cpp" || lang == "c#"
    puts "#{lang[c]}#{str}"
  else
    puts "unrecognized language found. supported languages are"
    langs.each_key {|k| puts "   #{k}"}
    exit
  end
else
  puts "#{langs[lang]} #{str}"
end
```

Comment: The Ruby convention is to use "snake-case" (lower case letters, digits and underscores) for names of variables and methods, so you'd commonly see your method `readFile` written `read_file`. You don't have to do that, but 99% of the Ruby code you'll see follows that convention.

Comment: I suggest you post this over on codereview.stackexchange.com, you will get good advice on how to make it more clear, concise, and rubylike.

Comment: @MarkThomas [codereview.se] expects posted code to be working as intended.  Everything else (including this, it seems) is considered off-topic.

Comment: What I meant was now that it is answered (and presumably working), there is an opportunity to improve it further.

Comment: Thank you both, I actually didn't know that ruby convention existed (perhaps me naming the method that way is a leftover from my C days), and will certainly take your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `fixnewlines` and change `readFile`:

```
def readFile(path)
  File.read(path).gsub("\n", '\n')
end
```

Hope it helps. On Windows use `\r\n` instead of `\n`. There's no need to escape slashes inside single brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which platform you're using. Unix uses `\n` as line ending characters, whereas windows uses `\r\n`. It looks like you're replacing all new line characters though with `\\n` which escapes the new line character which I would not expect to work on either platform.

Comment: Hi; Thanks for that! I kinda figured that it had something to do with the way I was writing the string (as in, i realized that I was escaping my escape, writing '\', followed by a 'n', causing a \n newline to be parsed). My question is actually more how to write a \n to a file (or stdout, it doesn't matter, but I figured it'd be the same either way) without it causing a newline to be parsed.